# ASP.NET 5 Project not serving index.html

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, iis

I'm following along with a beginner's tutorial for ASP.NET 5 and MVC6, and I've run into a wall regarding my first ever project. I have an app that should simply serve `index.html` as a static file from the `wwwroot` folder. However, when I run the project, I get a 404 error.

My code is as follows:

**startup.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace TheWorld
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            //app.Run(async (context) =>
            //{
            //    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            //});
        }
    }
}
```

**project.json**

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer to this question. I needed to change `project.json` to look like this:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },
```

and change my `startup.cs` file to include the following line:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseFileServer();

    //app.Run(async (context) =>
    //{
    //    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
    //});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add app.UseStaticFiles(); in your Configure method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

Add this Dependancy to project.Json file

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

Comment: I just edited my post because I forgot to mention -- when I add that line of code, I get this error: http://i.imgur.com/aJB5oPf.png

Comment: I've added the dependency `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final"` which resolves my error in the editor, but my app is still 404ing when trying to serve `index.html` from the `wwwroot` folder.